# Greenery on a planet without large oceans

Tags: climate, weather, agriculture

I want to create a planet that is mostly covered in land mass, with large amounts of forest, grassland, and farmland, but does NOT have large oceans. I envision the planet to have lots of lakes of various sizes (including very large ones,) tons of rivers and streams, and maybe a few small seas.

I know that on Earth, the oceans regulate the weather systems that allow us to have rain and green areas. Would a greater number of lakes and rivers than we have on Earth, distributed evenly over the planet, create the same effect?

Comment: You're missing some critical details. For example, it would be plausible to have a world-wide swamp filled with mangrove trees. That's a world-wide forest with no oceans that would nevertheless have rain and sensible weather patterns. The problem is, you didn't mention what kinds of trees you'd be willing to permit. You also don't mention the planet's volcanism (mountain building) or tectonic activity (mountain and chasm building). If you have enough water to keep a lot of trees alive, the water must be somewhere and a world-wide ground-level water table strains credulity.

Comment: Interesting! I'd never considered "swamp world"! I wonder if people started to build cities on a world-wide swamp planet if they would disrupt the environment too much and mess up the weather patterns.

Comment: No more or less than here on Earth. Just a different set of biomes, which means the specific details change but not the general mechanisms.

Comment: This scenario exists on Earth, and it is what we call "swamps". Siberia is essentially just one massive swamp.

Comment: The vast majority of moisture in a rainforest is created by the rainforest itself. Plants exude water vapor through their leaves, so much so, they themselves produce clouds and rain and cause the high air moisture. For a large part, they're closed systems. They've also formed during a time when Earth was much more moist than today and now couldn't even form (so, if we keep destroying our rainforests as much as we do, at some point, we'll lose them forever once we broke their self-sustaining capability). Once you figured out how your forests formed, keeping them alive isn't a big issue anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Depends of how large is their total surface area, and how much water they contain.

They would have sort-of the same effect if they would add up to the same area as Earth's oceans *and* they would contain a similar amount of water. (Those are very deep lakes, in the style of Lake Baikal.) Otherwise their effect would be different.

- If their total surface area is significantly smaller than the area of Earth's oceans then most of the planet will be very dry. Desert, not forest.

  <sup>And if the total surface area of the lakes is too small then the water cycle will be sufficiently strongly disrupted as to make the lakes dry up in the long run.</sup>
- If they contain much less water than Earth's oceans then their moderation effect on summers and winters will be very much reduced.

Note that some important effects, such as carrying huge amounts of heat from the Equator to northern latitudes, just cannot be simulated by a patchwork of disconnected lakes.

Comment: Yes, it's fine if the planet has an earth-like amount of water, so long as it can be distributed differently. Both fresh and salt water are fine. I actually didn't think of the lakes as all disconnected. I was thinking of lots of big rivers, and these could connect lakes. 

I'm hoping for more of a balance between land and water than we have on Earth, so that the land masses are not so far apart. I'm wondering if this kind of arrangement could result in lots of arable land (some deserts are okay, too, and so are seas, just not ones as big as our biggest oceans.)

Comment: @Angelique Rivers send water downstream, and they always have only one exit point, the one of lowest elevation, thus one lake can be fed by several others but can only ever feed one. If you want to connect many lakes with rivers, eventually all the water ends in one big lake and then you need enough evaporation and sping water to balance out the enormous influx or else the uphill lakes will slowly drain out into the downstream ones. I don't know if this is possible with a large network of lakes without eventually ending up with an ocean.

Comment: @Angelique Also, such a network of rivers and lakes will still not be able to distribute temperature from the equator to the poles and back. Look at how the gulf stream operates; warm equatorial surface water travels to the poles, where it cools and due to a rising density then sinks to the bottom of the ocean, where it then travels back to the equator to heat up again and then rises back to the surface as the density decreases. This is a loop you cannot reproduce with rivers and lakes. And it will likely have serious effects on the climate.

Comment: It sounds like oceans are a must! What if the planet's surface ad several evenly-distributed small continents? Like many Australias?

Comment: @Angelique: *"Several evenly-distributed small continents":* Yes, Earth was like that on several different occasions in the past 1000 million years. Wikimedia has a [nice animation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tectonic_plate_model_1Ga.webm) of the evolution of continents of Earth during the last billion years. (Continents are not eternal structures. Over geological time, they break up into pieces which move independently, and eventually join up in a different configuration. For example, India collided and fused with Asia about 20 million years ago; before that, it was separate.)

Comment: @ AlexP Wow! I knew about Pangea, but didn't know until now that there have been many super-continents, with the land breaking apart and reforming. Well, it looks for my world, "many Australias" it is!

Answer (score 3):

#### Much reduced plate tectonics

Plate tectonics are aided by the presence of water. Water in rocks decrease melt temperature. Large amounts of earths water have been subducted. This mechanism Could eventually Decrease ocean size/depth due to less water on surface. This suggest decreased plate tectonics. which means decreased mineral presence.  Unknown affect on climate, will certainly affect industrialization. May affect plant variation. Fewer trace minerals for some compounds.

#### Still will have salt basins

Water is a solvent. Many salts are readily dissolved. With water draining into various basins, Several of those basins will become salty. Just saying there will eventually be seas. To have exclusive freshwater lakes is very implausible, if that is the intent.

#### Ice ball.

If The planet dips into ice age, More likely to be locked permanently into ice age. Less places for life to not be frozen. Water is dark and absorbs a lot of solar energy. Land and ice reflect more light tending to keep the planet cool.

Earth spent something like a billion years in this setup so very plausible to have a dryer world get stuck this way.

#### Sandy ice ice ball / Global desert.

Another very likely scenario in the long run. Polar ice increasingly trapping more moisture. A hot equatorial zone become dry desert as evaporated water eventually all gets trapped in polar ice.  So baked dry equator, frozen dry poles. Seconal variation allow baking of water out to the poles.
I would anticipate an early ice ball would transition to this over time.

#### Conclusion

While it would not be impossible to have a low water green planet, It is going to be more delicate, more likely to end up trapped in a non green state with positive feedback loops keeping it away from being green.

Comment: The planet can have both salt water and fresh water, and it can have seas, but I'm hoping for more of a balance between land and water than we have on Earth, so that the land masses are not so far apart. I'm wondering if this kind of arrangement could result in lots of arable land (some deserts are okay, too.)